# Date and Time in Log file

Tags: sybase, sybase-sql-anywhere

I've the translated Sybase ASA 9 log file, and the log looks like

```
--UPDATE-1120-05402698411
UPDATE DBA.titulo_receber
   SET dt_pagto='2014/apr/28 11:06:08.593',
       id_situacao='BA',
       vl_pago=90,
       cd_empresa_baixa=5,
       cd_usuario_baixa=197,
       nr_recebimento=5015693,
       dt_manutencao='2014/apr/28 11:08:22.949895'
 WHERE cd_empresa=3
   AND nr_titulo=20154
   AND nr_parcela=5
   AND serie='CF05'
go
--INSERT-1120-05402698481
INSERT INTO DBA.mensagem(nr_mensagem,dt_mensagem,hora,cd_usuario_remetente,
      cd_usuario_destinatario,id_situacao,assunto,texto,id_confirmacao,
      dt_recebido,nr_mensagem_resposta,dt_mensagem_enviada,dt_ult_alteracao)
VALUES (50019297,'2014/apr/28 00:00','11:07:36.0',197,59,'N','TITULO BAIXADO','Empresa Venda: Loja3\x0D\x0AEmpresa Baixa: Loja5\x0D\x0ACliente: 3340-EZIONEI CONSTANTINO (Cliente da Loja3)\x0D\x0AT�tulo(s): 20154/05  R$ 90,00\x0D\x0ATOTAL PAGO: R$ 90,00','N',NULL,NULL,'2014/apr/28 11:06:08.593','2014/apr/28 11:08:22.952065')
go
--COMMIT-1120-05402701966
COMMIT WORK
go
```

I need to know the date and time in the "--UPDATE" / "--INSERT" and "--COMMIT" were executed in the db.

I can't find in the Sybase's help file nor in my search in Internet.

Kind Regards,
William Bertan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that information is not available. The transaction log file doesn't store information to that level of detail for most statements. You can get the date and time for connection attempts and checkpoints, but not for DDL statements.

*Disclaimer: I work for SAP in SQL Anywhere engineering.*